# How to add "missing" braces with Netbeans when (re)Fromat code (Alt+Shift+F)?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm updating an old PHP project which coding style is not to my liking. When I reformat the code with Alt+Shift+F in Netbeans 8 everything is fine except this:

```
if (something)
    doif;
else
    doelse;
```

I would expect:

```
if (something) {
    doif;
} else {
    doelse;
}
```

Everything if configured correctly for the braces and the autocomplete works well for new code but the existing code is not updated to these rules when using (re)Format. Is there a way to add these "missing" braces automatically?

Comment: I am not sure how you would fix this however why would you want it with the {curly brackets} when you don't need them in this case anyway?

Comment: Yes I know they are not required but it could lead to hard to find bugs... And the newer projects always have the braces. So I want to unify the code styling across the codebase.

Comment: How would the curly brackets being there help you to find bugs? It looks much cleaner without them.

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no for example... Its more of a preference but in my code it's a requirement. So I must update the non-compliant code. But would dislike to do this manually...

Comment: Ah okay I see what you mean they are more error prone however in a nice IDE like Net Beans if you add another statement it will indent it differently so you will notice as soon as you make the mistake anyway. However when it comes to commenting code you would just have to be extra careful I guess but I do see why you want Net Beans to keep them.

Comment: The benefit you're trying to achieve is detecting incorrectly formed if statements using visual indenting. If you spot something incorrectly indented visually then you know there's a mistake. If you're using netbeans to reformat the code then the visual indent error clue will disappear. So I don't think doing this will get you the benefit you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It's not a benefit, it's a requirement... My codebase have a standard and this old code does not fit the new standard. We can argue about the benefit or not but in my case it's a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the line of code **after** the if an hit alt+enter. It should give you the option to "Add Braces"!

If not, go to options/editor/hints and activate hints for braces in lang PHP.

P.S.: You will still have to hit alt+enter for each line where braces are missing!